# CvInvoke.cvMul exception

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to multiply the fundamental matrix with a one column matrix (a 2D homogeneous coordinates), but I get the following error: `CvException occurred - OpenCV: src1.size == dst.size && src1.channels() == dst.channels()`

The code looks like this:

```
IntPtr fundamentalMatrix = CvInvoke.cvCreateMat(3, 3, MAT_DEPTH.CV_32F);

[... finding the fundamental matrix ...]

IntPtr cam1PointRef = CvInvoke.cvCreateMat(3, 1, MAT_DEPTH.CV_32F);
IntPtr cam2PointRef = CvInvoke.cvCreateMat(3, 1, MAT_DEPTH.CV_32F);

//cam1Point is known
CvInvoke.cvSet2D(cam1PointRef, 0, 0, new MCvScalar(cam1Point.X));
CvInvoke.cvSet2D(cam1PointRef, 1, 0, new MCvScalar(cam1Point.Y));
CvInvoke.cvSet2D(cam1PointRef, 2, 0, new MCvScalar(1));

CvInvoke.cvMul(fundamentalMatrix, cam1PointRef, cam2PointRef, 1);

Matrix<float> cam2PointMat = new Matrix<float>(3, 1, cam2PointRef);

PointF cam2Point = new PointF();
cam2Point.X = cam2PointMat[0, 0] / cam2PointMat[0, 2];
cam2Point.Y = cam2PointMat[0, 1] / cam2PointMat[0, 2];
```

If i invert the multiplication order like this: `CvInvoke.cvMul(cam1PointRef, fundamentalMatrix, cam2PointRef, 1);` I get another exception:

`OpenCV: The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array'`

What I'm doing wrong? Why I can not multiply (3 x 3) matrix with (3 x 1) matrix for getting the corespondent point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now I have not my pc with me, but you should make it simpler using Matrix<,> generic class instead of old cvinvoke syntax. Using matrix class I never find any issues in matrix operation.

Your error consist on multipling matrices using an array multiplication method;

> ***cvmul***
>   Calculates per-element product of two arrays dst(I)=scale*src1(I)*src2(I) All the arrays must have the same type,
>   and the same size (or ROI size)

```
public static void cvMul(
    IntPtr  src1,
    IntPtr  src2,
    IntPtr  dst,
    double  scale
)
```